# Videos upon click won't load the correct video

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a list of videos that upon clicking will open up in a modal. However, when I click on one it loads the first video for each one even though they are different videos. My question is how would I go about making sure each video is the same video that was clicked to appear in the modal.

Here is my code I have in place:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // event handler on click video
    $('#left-videos video').on('click', function() {
        document.getElementById("v-modal").style.display = "block";

        $('#clicked-video').html("<video class=\"w3-round w3-border\" width=\"300\" height=\"170\" id=\"other-video\" controls><source src=" + $('video source').attr('src') + " type=\"video/mp4\"></video>");
    });
</script>

<!-- video modal -->
<div class="w3-modal" id="v-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content w3-card-4 w3-theme-d2 w3-round" style="width: 400px;">
        <div class="w3-container">
            <p class="w3-center w3-small" id="video-modal">
                <span onclick="document.getElementById('v-modal').style.display = 'none'" class="w3-closebtn" id="close-video">&times;</span>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('#close-video').on('click', function() {
                        $('video').trigger('pause');
                    });
                </script>
            </p>

            <div class="w3-row-padding w3-center" id="clicked-video"></div>

            <br><br>

            <div class="w3-clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end video modal -->
```

To help better explain, here is a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the 2nd video is different but it shows up the 1st video in the modal.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Oh, one more thing, I'm not sure it will make a difference but here is the php code I have in place to get all the videos:

```
$video_dir = @array_diff(scandir(getcwd() . '/public/images/profile/' . $params . '/videos/', 1), array('.', '..'));

if (count($video_dir) > 0) {
    $videos = array();

    foreach ($video_dir as $video) {
        $videos[] = "<video style=\"width: 100%; height: 100%;\" class=\"w3-margin-bottom w3-round w3-border\">
           <source src=\"/images/profile/$params/videos/$video\" type=\"video/mp4\">
        </video>";
    }

    natsort($videos);

    $layout->setVariable('my_videos', $videos);
}
```

and the view section

```
<div id="side-5" class="w3-accordion-content w3-container">
    <div class="w3-row-padding" id="left-videos">
    <br>
        <?php
            if (count($this->layout()->my_videos) > 0):
                foreach ($this->layout()->my_videos as $vids):
        ?>

        <div class="w3-half">
            <?php echo $vids; ?>
        </div>

        <?php
                endforeach;
            else:
        ?>
              <p>Upload <a href="<?php echo $this->url('members/profile', array('action' => 'upload-file')); ?>">videos</a>!</p> 
        <?php

            endif;
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I assume the mistake is: **$('video source').attr('src')** . Try changing that with **$(this).find('source').attr('src')**

Comment: thanks, that fixed it! :)

Comment: @gaetanoM answer worked `$(this).find('source').attr('src')`

Comment: glad to help you